# Using x86dbg valid opcodes produce '??? invalid instruction' output

Tags: disassembly, x86, tools

Using the most recent ( as of today ) version of x86dbg I have a problem that follow every executable I have tried.

The disassembler in the CPU window, look at the 5th line from the top:

[image: screenshot]

Any ideas why this is happening and or suggestions to correct it?

Comment: Looks like a bug in their disassembler engine. I'd recommend [notifying them](http://x64dbg.com/#contact).

Comment: Never mind... I see [you just did](https://github.com/x64dbg/x64dbg/issues/795) :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to a software bug or a software malfunction. Nothing to do with RE.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be [an actual bug](https://github.com/x64dbg/x64dbg/issues/795).
The x86dbg team  has found and already fixed it. The fix should be in tonight's snapshot (Jun 23 2016).

Comment: rep probably doesnt allow for commenting just yet :)